# Update a document inside a document and inside a document

Tags: c#, mongodb

Here's my Application document

```
{
  "_id": "binary_stuff",
  "Name": "MyApplication",
  "Settings": [
    {
      "_id": "binary_stuff",
      "Key": "ImportDirectory",
      "Value": "C:\data",
      "Overrides": [{
             "_id": "binary_stuff",
             "NewValue": "C:\anotherData"
       }]
    },
}
```

I know how to add a Settings subdocument but how can I add a new Override "subsubdocument".

I tried:

```
var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", applicationId), Query.EQ("Settings._id", settingId));
var update = Update.AddToSetWrapped("Settings.Overrides", overrideViewModel.ToBsonDocument());
Run(database => database.Applications().Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Upsert, SafeMode.True));
```

It does nothing...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks guys !!

Comment: you need the <insert whatever mongo mapping/wrapper you use> equivalent of :

db.yourcollection.update({..}, {$push:{'Settings.Overrides':{"_id":"morestuff", "NewValue":"Something"}}})

Comment: Hi @Remon van Vliet I don't understand...

Comment: Actually, I do get an error when my query is performed. I have: Safemode detected an error: can't append to array using string field name [Overrides] (response: { "err" : "can't append to array using string field name [Overrides]", "code" : 13048, "n" : 0, "connectionId" : 60, "ok" : 1 })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I had to use the operational $

```
var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", applicationId), Query.EQ("Settings._id", settingId)); 
var update = Update.AddToSetWrapped("Settings.Overrides", overrideViewModel.ToBsonDocument()); 
Run(database => database.Applications().Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Upsert, SafeMode.True));
```

Comment: John, your answer code sample is same as the one posted in your question. Can you explain what operational $ you have added? thanks